# TypeError: _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.goToRedeem is not a function

Tags: reactjs, routes, navigation, native, scene

I'm very new to react native and I'm having issue with Routes Action.home(). Can anyone help, thanks advance..

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './Login';
import Redeem from './Redeem';

const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Scene key="root">
      <Scene
        key="home"
        component={Login}
        title="Login"
        hideNavBar={true}
        initial={true}
        duration={0}
      />
      <Scene key="redeem" component={Redeem} title="Redeem" />
    </Scene>
  </Router>
);

    const goToRedeem = () => {
        Actions.goToRedeem();
      };

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",

onPress={goToRedeem} gives
```

TypeError: _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.goToRedeem is not a function. (In '_reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.goToRedeem()', '_reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.goToRedeem' is undefined)

Answer (score 2):

First import Actions from react-native-router-flux

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

And you had declared your key as redeem and your calling it as goToRedeem()

Change

```
Actions.goToRedeem();
```

to

```
Actions.redeem();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Did you import `Actions` from `react-native-router-flux` ?